# Recommender system based on binary likes/disklikes?

Tags: recommender-system, naive-bayes-classifier

I am building a recommender system. I have a list that shows me what a user has disliked and I use it to create a dataset. The dataset shows me: `ProductID, Likes, Disklikes` where the values are counts from other users that have disliked the same products.

What are some of the algorithmic approaches I can use from this base? From this data I know I can get a probability. How would I also get a weighted average? Maybe some sort of Bayesian filtering approach is called for in these scenarios?

Comment: You don't have an access to likes/dislikes of a product per user?

Comment: @BartłomiejTwardowski I do. However, that is in a sparse matrix and I have consolidated that info into the table columns I defined above. I am focusing more on a community recommender rather than a content recommender

Comment: Search for "Binary/boolean matrix factorization".

Comment: Content-Based Recommender is when you use the actual information about the product, e.d. title, category, price, desc. Here, you have product-users events (like/dislike). So you will probably go for Collaborative-Filtering. Thus, as previous comment suggested you can use MF. However, most of MF are prepared for positive-implicit feedback. I would suggest with simpler approach - kNN with your own sim(u,u) function that will take likes/dislikes into account.